# Do matrices with multiplication and Moore-Penrose inverse form a regular semigroupoid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, pseudoinverse, inverse-semigroups

## Definition

$\left\langle S, \otimes \right\rangle$ is a regular semigroup means

1. The operation $\otimes$ is closed on $S$: $\forall s_1, s_2 \in S: s_1 \otimes s_2 \in S$
2. The operation $\otimes$ is associative: $\forall s_1, s_2, s_3 \in S: s_1 \otimes \left( s_2 \otimes s_3 \right) = \left( s_1 \otimes s_2 \right) \otimes s_3$
3. For each $s \in S$ there is a $s' \in S$ (maybe not unique) such that $s \otimes s' \otimes s = s$ and $s' \otimes s \otimes s' = s'$

Being an inverse semigroup means uniqueness of the inverse.

## Example

Let's take a look at the specific example.
A set of square matrices of fixed size is closed under the matrix multiplication, so forms a regular semigroup (given the Moore-Penrose inverse as the inverse because not all matrices are invertible).
The Moore-Penrose inverse (pseudoinverse) $A^+$ is defined for any matrix as $\forall n, m \in \mathbb{N}^+: \forall A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}: A A^+ A = A, A^+ A A^+ = A^+$. It's unique so it forms an inverse semigroop as well as less restrictive regular semigroup.

## Problem

In turn, the set of all real-valued matrices is not closed under the matrix multiplication, so it's not a regular semigroup. Though, it's associative and has a pseudo-inverse. I would call such structure **regular semigroupoid** (or **inverse semigroupoid** if being more restrictive and precise).

The problem: I can't find a lot about the regular semigroupoid (and inverse semigroupoid), and cannot find mentions of Moore-Penrose inverse and matrices as the example. The articles I've found are "E-free objects and e-locality for completely regular semigroups" by Peter R. Jones (referencing regular semigroupoid) and "Free inverse monoids and graph immersions" by S. W. Margolis and J. C. Meakin (referencing inverse semigroupoid).

## Question

- Do matrices with multiplication and Moore-Penrose inverse form a regular semigroupoid?
- Is my understanding of regular and inverse semigroupoids correct?
- Why are regular and inverse semigroupoids not so popular?